# more info for R DBI::dbSendQuery?

Tags: r, r-dbi

Here is a line of code that used to work:

```
res <- DBI::dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT 1")
```

Now it says:

```
 Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ",  : 
  Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for SELECT 1 (Error executing query)
```

I'm connecting to a Presto instance. Likely there's a connection problem or some other non-SQL problem.

How do I get more logging or debug information from this interface?  I'm using DBI 0.7, R 3.4.3 on OS X (`darwin15.6.0`).

I read some of [the docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/DBI.pdf), and I don't see an interface to turn on logging, or debug info.  Maybe a connection parameter?

Comment: Does the problem exist after updating R and the relevant packages?  DBI 0.7 was released ago (v1.0 is current).  The current R is 3.5.0.  I know this doesn't answer your real question about providing debugging info.  I would like to know that.

Comment: Thanks for the thought. I installed DBI 1.0.0, and get the same message. :/